# Stacked up redirects are skipped and only the last one is completed

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

If you stack up redirects in JS, it will run only the last one. Do you know why is that?

Consider the following code:

```
const redirect = () => {
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
  window.location = 'https://www.example.com';
  window.location = 'https://www.bing.com';
};
```

If you run that on your browser you will see that it goes directly on bing.com and even if you preserve the network tab you'll see that the other two locations aren't even requested.

Why is that? Why does it skip the first ones and goes straight to the last one instead of going straight to the first one?

So basically, what is happening when you do `window.location = URL` and what other ways are there that give us more control over the redirect?

Comment: There is no guarantee that all browsers will do this. Using just one redirect would give you complete control.

Comment: How would you implement interpreting your snippet if you were a Web browser? At what point should it stop visiting one URL and start visiting another? Should it be some arbitrary time, like 2 seconds? Or should it guarantee that it receives a response from the Web server on the first URL, and as soon as that proceed to the next one and so on?

Comment: @amn If we take under consideration that JS is synchronous the logical thing to do would be to go on the second redirect (window.location = URL) only after the first one is finished. Now the first one can be finished in one of two ways: 1. It succeeded, which means that all remaining code from the previous URL is discarded for security reasons and no other redirect is even evaluated. 2. It failed, which means that the execution moves to the next line and the next redirect.

Comment: The behavior of a compliant user agent with regard to assigning a value to a `Location` object (typically a property named `location` on a `Window` or `Document` object) is specified to some degree by the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface). I haven't read and grokked the particulars of the behavior (because grokking a lot of that stuff is hard) but you may find an answer there, if it specifies the behavior to a sufficient degree, that is.

Comment: JavaScript *interpreter machine* is synchronous, *not* procedures it enables, including switching browser contexts -- if you think the browser will *pause* script execution while fetching a new resource at a new URL through `location` assignment, you're mistaken -- it merely *enqueues* a task that does the navigation, your script will continue execution as soon as that task can *start*, not as soon as it actually finishes. This is supported by your own observation and is alluded to in the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigating-across-documents).

Answer (score 2):

Redirects are implemented by web-browsers. An implementation might prefer to finish the execution of everything and instantly start loading the new page. Another approach, with better UX is to let the scripts run before loading the other page, because that's friendlier for the human eye. Now, if you say

```
window.location = url1;
//...
window.location = url2;
```

and if we assume that the script runs before the other page is requested, then `url2` will be the new value of `window.location` when the redirection starts. A very simple solution is to do something like:

```
var redirectPath;
function redirect(path) {
    if (redirectPath === undefined) (window.location = redirectPath = path);
}
```

you can even extend this, implementing something more elegant, but really, why would we want to change the value of `window.location` several times? This sounds like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Say that you are the developer of an app which has a lite and a pro version of itself and you want to redirect to a specific page within your app using deeplinks. In that case, you can't know from the browser which app the user has installed, so the only way to open the correct one is to try both deeplinks. In that case, you need a redirect and then another one in the case the first one fails.

Comment: `An implementation might prefer to finish execution of everything and instantly start loading new page` -- no, this is simply not the case. As I mentioned in my answer, the behavior that a compliant implementation will align itself with, [is specified](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigating-across-documents), and we should be grateful that it is -- if I am going to implement a Web browser, what should it do, exactly, when a script sets `location`?

Comment: @ChristosMaris you can send a request via Javascript without a redirect and determine what the answer is. Or you can open a page inside an invisible iFrame and communicate between the parent and the child page.

Comment: @LajosArpad Those two ways don't work anymore: you can't fetch a deeplink or open it using an iframe anymore.

Comment: @ChristosMaris yes, you can. You can send an AJAX request and handle the response. I do that daily successfully. As about the iframe, you can open any page in an iframe. If your page and the iframe are from the same domain, you can establish communication between the two. If they are from different domains and you have control on the source-code of both, then you can, then you can post messages between the two.

Comment: @ChristosMaris also, you can use an intermediate page, which will redirect to the correct version.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm doing the thing with the intermediate pages right, but how do you send AJAX requests to the deeplinks? Say you have this deeplink: "com.company.android://open/app", how would you do it?

Comment: @ChristosMaris a deep link is a link to a page other than the homepage. You can easily send AJAX request to that kind of deep link. The deep link you have given seems to be different, the ://open/app is unusual, which probably explains why sending an AJAX request to your deep link does not work. Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve with the deep link you have given?

Comment: @LajosArpad A deeplink is a link to a mobile app rather than a webpage. The deeplink in question basically says: open the app called "company" and redirect to the page "open/app", which page can be whatever you want it to be (you code that in the app). So a deeplink is a link to an installed app in your device and not to another webpage.

Comment: This starts to look like a classical example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I would advise you to amend your question where you make it clear what you *actually* want to accomplish, as opposed to asking how to visit multiple URLs, which is evidently not your *actual* question. Does a single `location = "com.example.app://foo/bar"` work? As in, does it cause application to open at the specified screen?

Answer (score 0):

Executing a script statement like `window.location = "http://www.example.com";` does not result in the effect of being at another document location by the time next JavaScript statement is executed. A compliant user agent does not *immediately* and *atomically* (with respect to the currently executing script) switch location.

The procedure of navigation that will take place as a result of a `location` assignment statement like above, consists of several steps specified by [the HTML standard, section 7.8.1, among others](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigating-across-documents).

In short, a background (to the script intepreter) task is created and queued for execution (again, parallel to the script interpreter) for every request to navigate the window.

Quoting step 7 from the list of steps in the procedure the section linked above defines, which is of particular interest here:

> 7. Cancel any preexisting but not yet mature attempt to navigate browsingContext, [...]

Thus it would make sense to think that all redirections your `location` assignments create, end up being canceled by the subsequent redirection, save for the last (3rd) such attempt, which is able to proceed to "maturity".

Your assumptions about how document redirection should work in reaction to JavaScript statement execution, appear to be flawed to me.

If you want to script reliably visiting multiple locations *in sequence*, in accordance with specified platform behavior, so your application has a higher chance of working some years down the line, I'd advise looking into [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/), [`fetch`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), [`sendBeacon`](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#sec-sendBeacon-method) or perhaps creating `link` or some other link-like elements (or an `iframe`) on your application document to cause the user agent to "visit" some URLs of your choosing.

One interesting issue with visiting URLs outside your domain of control, is that the scope of your scripts is your Web application, or at best a domain or domains you control. Once the user agent leaves your domain, it executes scripts outside of your control, on pages you don't control, and none of your scripts will be loaded or executed.

If you just want to fetch resources without redirecting the top window there, with `fetch` you could do this:

```
function redirect_in_sequence(URLs) {
    function next() {
        fetch(URLs.shift()).then(response => {
            if(URLs.length) next();
        });
    }
}
redirect_in_sequence([ "http://example1.com", "http://example2.com", "http://example3.com" ]);
```

Your question asks "why", not "what" or "how", so I will leave this at that.

In any case you should make yourself familiar with how script execution works in a user agent, this is related to how (and when) events are queued and dispatched, and as we see in this case, how user agents navigate, whether you type an address yourself in a GUI of sorts or assign a value to `document.location` or `window.location`, among other things.
To re-iterate my comment to your question, JavaScript execution is synchronous with respect to executing statements in strict order, but the behavior these statements invoke results in all kinds of parallel execution. In fact, at any point in time, a user agent has several groups of background tasks of different kind going on. Suffice to say, there are technical and historical reasons for this, and not all of them are entirely justified, but here we are.